# What is the number of terms in this series $1+0.5+0.25+\ldots+0.5^{n−1}$? And what is the sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> What is the number of terms in this series $1+0.5+0.25+\ldots+0.5^{n−1}$? And what is the sum?

I stumped by this question, but have a feeling the answer's really obvious:S
Am I supposed to get an actual number as the answer?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well you have $n$ terms. This is just $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{-k} = 2 - 2^{1-n}$...

Answer (score 1):

You have $n$ terms, so the first part was easy.

Ponder the sum $1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^N$

Multiply that by $1-x$ and see all the terms that cancel.

You'll be left with $1 - x^{N+1}$.

So the sum equaled $\frac{1 - x^{N+1}}{1-x}$

And there's your answer.

Comment: Please use mathjax/latex to typeset math. [Here is the guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)!

Comment: @Winther  Will do. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

use the geometric series 
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+.....x^n$$
$$\frac{1}{1-x}-1=x+x^2+x^3+.....x^n$$
$$\frac{1}{1-x}-1=x(1+x+x^2+x^3+.....x^{n-1})$$
$$\frac{x}{1-x}=x(1+x+x^2+x^3+.....x^{n-1})$$

hence
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=(1+x+x^2+x^3+.....x^{n-1})$$

$|x|<1$
plug $x=0.5$
$$\frac{1}{1-0.5}=2$$

Comment: That's not true. $\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\dotsb$, the infinite sequence. For the finite sequence, we have $\frac{1-x^{\large n+1}}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\dotsb+x^n$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus Is correct. The term dissappears for infinite sums as $x^{n+1}\to 0$ when $n\to \infty$ (for $|x|<1$).